# Python 'not in' operator not working correctly?

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator, definitions

```
def step(g, m, n):
    notstorage=[]
    actualvalues =[]
    for i in range(m, (n+1)):
        for primechecker in range(2,i):
            if i % primechecker == 0:
                notstorage.append(i)



    for value in range(m, (n+1)):
        if (value) and (value+g) not in set(notstorage):
            actualvalues.append(value)
            actualvalues.append(value+g)
            break
    return(actualvalues)
```

In the above code I'm trying to figure out which numbers are prime and create a list that checks if there are two prime numbers separated by a certain number (g). I'm having issues because for some reason the number 303 is being returned as a prime number when it clearly is not since it is divisible by 3.... I'm not sure why the code isn't working properly?

When I input:

```
step(4,300,400)
```

I am expecting an output of (307,311) since those are the first 2 prime numbers that are 4 numbers apart but instead I get a return of (303, 307)

Not sure what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this syntax instead:

`if (value) not in set(notstorage) and (value+g) not in set(notstorage):`

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware that the syntax I was using wasn't checking the same way for both value and value+g. Much appreciated!

Comment: Question: If I want to add a else operator that returns a specific answer if it can't find any 2 prime numbers separated by a certain number (g) how would I go about doing that, but having it outside of the original loop? I tried adding an else: return('None available') at the very end but that didn't work because then everything just returned that.

Comment: This is unclear and another question altogether, I suggest you create a new one and post all the new relevant code to make it clear

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code., but I think all you need is `return values` in the `for` loop when you find them (instead of `break`), and at the end `else: return 'none found'`

Comment: Ok I'll make a new question. Thanks for your help with this one!

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
(value) and (value+g) not in set(notstorage)
```

checks if `(value)` evaluates to `True`, and that `(value+g) not in set(notstorage)` evaluates to `True`.

It does *not* check if both `(value)` and `(value+g)` are not in the set.